# MongoDB is not updating all records, even with multi set to true

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection representing Wikipedia pages, with title, categories and links, as represented below.

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1975),
    "Categories" : [ 
        "pacific ocean"
    ],
    "Links" : [ 
        "volcano", 
        "trench", 
        "water", 
        ...
        "kilometer", 
        "plate tectonics", 
        "el niño"
    ],
    "Title" : "pacific ocean"
}
```

I need to update some values in the Links array, to do this, I'm doing the following.

```
db.WikipediaArticles.update({Links:"kilometer"}, {$set: {"Links.$": "kilometre"}}, {upsert:false, multi:true})
```

This, however, is not updating all documents (as expected) and I end up having to run it 3-4 times to have all records updated. Is there anyway I can guarantee that all documents are updated?

Comment: how big is the collection, and how long are you waiting? in very large collections, updates do not process immediately-- these operations are not atomic. see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-acid-transactions

Comment: It's a decently sized collection (count is 153818) and storage size is 98553856 (bytes I reckon). Should I just wait a while? I'm not really specifying any wait times....

Comment: yes, unfortunately this is a limitation of mongodb. if there are reads going on, there is no guarantee that your multi-write will have fully processed.

Comment: Can `"kilometer"` appear multiple times in `Links`?  Is that why you're saying the behavior is "as expected"?

Comment: Yes, it most definitely appears multiple times in certain documents. That could be the issue I guess...

Comment: That's your issue then, as `$` will only identify the index of the _first_ matching element in `Links`.  No way around it, you just need to keep running the command until no docs are affected.

Comment: @JohnnyHK well spotted-- I would recommend putting it as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` identifies the index of the *first* matching element in the query, so each time you run the `update` it will only modify at most one `Links` element per doc.

Because `Links` can contain multiple elements of `"kilometer"`, you need to keep running the `update` command until it reports that no docs were affected.